# Electron-builder .msi. How to prevent app to launch itself after installation

Tags: electron, windows-installer, electron-builder

I'm generating a .msi with electron-builder but when I install it, it always launch the application. Is it possible to prevent this?

I found the `runAfterFinish` option but it's only for nsis.

Comment: Why is this tagged with NSIS when you are using MSI?

Comment: Check the Finish/Complete dialog for the checkbox/event.

Comment: Actually my goal is to make a silent installation of my electron app. So I built a .msi and run msiexec.exe /quiet /i "myapp.msi". The quiet installation runs but I don't wan my app to open at the end of the silent installation

Answer (score 0):

I just added `runAfterFinish: false` to `"msi"` property and it worked.

```
"nsis": {
      "runAfterFinish": false
    },
"msi": {
      "runAfterFinish": false
    },
```